# Search the contents in the html

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

There are two different tags in the HTML which are `row0-1` and `row1-1`. I want to search for the contents in the HTML called `row1Time` from the `row1-1` tag.

Here's and example HTML:

```
<li class="zc-ssl-pg" id="row0-1" style="">
    <span id="row1Time" class="zc-ssl-pg-time">4:00 PM</span>
    <li class="zc-ssl-pg" id="row1-1" style="">
    <span id="row1Time" class="zc-ssl-pg-time">3:00 PM</span>
```

Here's my PHP:

```
    <?php
    $errmsg_arr = array();
    $errflag = false;
    $link;

    function db_connect()
    {
      define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
      define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
      define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
      define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

      $errmsg_arr = array();
      $errflag = false;
      $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

      if(!$link) 
      {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
      }

      $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
      if(!$db) 
      {
        die("Unable to select database");
      }
    }

    $links = $row['links'];
    include ('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html($links);
    //echo $row['links'];

    $base = $row['links'];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Create a DOM object
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $html->load($str);

    //get all category links
    /*foreach($html_base->find('a') as $element) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $element->href );
        echo "</pre>";
    }*/

    //$html_base->clear();
    //unset($html_base);

    $time1 = $html->find('span[id=row1Time]', 0)->plaintext;
    echo '<span id="time1">'.$time1.'</span> - ';
?>
```

When I tried to parse the contents from the HTML using this:

```
$time1 = $html->find('span[id=row1Time]', 0)->plaintext;
echo '<span id="time1">'.$time1.'</span> - ';
```

The return output I get is from the tags `row0-1` with `row1Time`:

```
4:00 PM
```

I want to search for the contents in the HTML from the tags `row1-1` with `row1Time` to get the return contains `3:00 PM`. Can you please help me get those contents using `simple_html_dom`?

Comment: Is it normal that there's no closing `<li>` tag ? If so, the html code is not valid, therefore traversing/searching through the dom won't be possible... You can still try `$html->find('span[id=row1-1]', 0)->next_sibling()->plaintext()` [not tested!]

Comment: @Enissay the end tag for LI is optional as long as there's another LI coming up or an end to the list. It's valid for HTML5. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html

Comment: @Enissay thank you for your reply. I tried this: `$time1 = $html->find('span[id=row1-1]', 0)->next_sibling()->plaintext();`, but I got an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function next_sibling() on a non-object. Any idea?

Comment: @netrox, I wasnt sure of that... Thanks for the info :)

Comment: What about `$time1 = $html->find('span[id=row1-1]', 0)->plaintext();`

Comment: @Enissay I still get the fatal error using the code you mentored. The error I get is `Fatal error: Call to a member function plaintext() on a non-object`

Comment: I based my answer on your try [the bad copy/paste habit], which contained errors already... Check my new answer bellow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistaken me with your errors... please check your html code carefully!

You want to get the text withing the span element which is inside the li node with the id 'row1-1'. This can be translated to `$html->find('li#row1-1', 0)->plaintext;`

This is A full working code:

```
$input =  <<<_DATA_
    <li class="zc-ssl-pg" id="row0-1" style="">
    <span id="row1Time" class="zc-ssl-pg-time">4:00 PM</span>
    <li class="zc-ssl-pg" id="row1-1" style="">
    <span id="row1Time2" class="zc-ssl-pg-time">3:00 PM</span>
_DATA_;

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($input);

$time1 = $html->find('li#row1-1', 0)->plaintext;

echo $time1;

// Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3:00 PM
```

Please refer to the [`PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for more informations...

Comment: thank you very much for this, sorry i realised that the website where I parsing the information from, they have change the time to confused me which it make me thinks it didn't work but it doesn't, so the code you post it actually works. Thank you!!!